# Makefile improvement when intermediate files do not really change

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile like this

```
all: *.foo
    ./finalstep *.foo > $@

%.foo: %.bar
    ./secondstep < $< > $@

%.bar: %.baz
    ./firststep < $< > $@
```

The thing is that *often* changes in a `.baz` file are minor in the sense that the `.bar` file produced after the change is the same (content-wise, or as would be detected by `diff`) as before the change.
Since `secondstep` and `finalstep` (and possible some more intermediate steps) are *expensive* it would be preferable if the lack of change in the `.bar` files could be detected and thus the invocation of `secondstep` (and maybe even `finalstep`) spared. Is there any way to achieve this?

My attempt to do something like this is as follows:

```
%.bar: %.baz
    touch $@; cp $@ $@.backup; ./firststep < $< > $@

%.foo: %.bar
    diff -q $< $<.backup || ./secondstep < $< > $@
```

But this has a lot of drawbacks (and does not work correctly if one invokes `make` with arguments).
Is there any better method? Basically, `make` should consider two different filetimes for `.bar` files: One that gets updated each time `firststep` is run and that is used to determine whether `.bar` itself needs to be remade. Another that is only updated when a run of `firststep` results in a net change of *content* of the file and that is used to determine whethr `.foo` needs to be remade ...

Comment: `But this has a lot of drawbacks` => what are those? `does not work correctly if one invokes make with arguments` => which ones?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca drawbacks: For example, the `.bar` files need to be and stay there. If they get deleted in a make as intermediate files then the whole backup comparison goes wrong. So when adding `new.baz`it is not enough to `make new.foo; make all` (or `make depend; make all` with automatic  dependencies treatment), but instead one has to `make new.bar` explcitly

Comment: Another drawback is that the comparison happens in the foo rule when in logically belongs to the bar rule. Somehow all my attempts with moving the logic there (`diff -q $@ $@.backup && mv $@.backup $@`) seemd to backfire in certain error situations

Comment: Please, share your thoughts on the solution posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should experiment with something like this *(not tested)*:

```
all: %.foo
    ./finalstep %.foo > $@

%.foo: %.bar
    @if [[ -f $< && -f $<.backup ]]; then   \
        if diff -q $< $<.backup; then       \
            echo "IDENTICAL => do nothing"; \
        else                                \
            echo "DIFFERENT => proceed";    \
            ./secondstep < $< > $@;         \
        fi;                                 \
    else                                    \
        echo "NOT FOUND => proceed";        \
        ./secondstep < $< > $@;             \
    fi;                                     \
    cp $< $<.backup

%.bar: %.baz
    ./firststep < $< > $@;
```

---

Basically, the intention of the big recipe is to handle all the relevant combinations of `$<` and `$<.backup` (in the same subshell!):

- both files present and equal (`diff` returns `0`) `=>` do nothing
- both files present and differ (`diff` returns `1`) `=>` execute
- one of the files not present `=>` execute

Whatever is the above choice, make a `backup` at the end.